# Define multiple symbols in Eclipse preprocessor settings

Tags: c, c-preprocessor, eclipse-cdt, mcu

Is there a way to define multiple symbols in one go in Eclipse?
I have a list of preprocessor symbols that need to be defined and adding one by one in the preprocessor settings seems to be too tedious. Is there a way to add the list of symbols in one batch?

Tried adding new defined symbol but this only allows to add 1 symbol at a time.

Comment: I would guess they are stored in the `.cproject` file, so you might edit this XML file directly.

Comment: Can you add an option to include an extra header for each file? Like `-imacro <file>` ? Then add your macros in that file.

Comment: I would use an extra header file with those global stuff and include in all C files. It helps when you move to another toolchain/IDE

Comment: I know they are stored in the .cproject, I was wondering if there is a software to manage this? @howlger

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way of achieving this is to copy all your defined symbols and pasting them in the defined symbols list, instead of using the "add" button.

You can ctrl+c and ctrl+v in the defined symbols list.

[Settings_Preprocessor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R3ZNl.png)